# PayPal Adaptive Payment using different currencies

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I have web page where I need to use paypal adaptive payment. Now I have issue by testing in sandbox testing environment.
This is paypal respond failure:

```
  <faultstring>The receiver test123@hotmail.com does not accept payments in this Currency</faultstring>
```

1 - Sender use test email paypal with USD currency
2 - Receiver use EUR currency
3 - Business side also use USD currencies.

Is it possible to make payment with different currencies with paypal adaptive payment, or is there anything more to do to enable this functionality ?

Answer (score 1):

Send the `currencyCode` field in your `PAY` action. This will make the sender pay in that currency, however.

See the [API Documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/Pay_API_Operation/) for more information on the fields in the `PAY` action.